# Displaying index of element after finding it

Tags: c++11

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    for(int i{1}; i <= s; i++) {
        int num_input;
        std::cin >> num_input;
        numbers.push_back(num_input);
    }

    int c_s;
    std::cin >> c_s;

    while(c_s--) {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;



        if(std::find(numbers.begin(),numbers.end(), n) != numbers.end()) {
            std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a coding problem on hacker rank that wants me to display the index of int when I find it, but I can't think of any way to do that. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index using `std::distance` on the iterator returned by `std::find`. You can change your code as follows

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(numbers.begin(),numbers.end(),n);
if(it != numbers.end()) {
    std::cout << "Yes, found at" << std::distance(numbers.begin(),it) << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I have one more question, the problem is also asking for "If the number is not present you have to print "No" (without the quotes) followed by the index of the next smallest number just greater than that number" how would I get that number? I am little confused on what its asking and cannot figure a solution to this one as well.

Comment: You can use `std::upper_bound()`. `upper_bound(numbers.begin(),numbers.end(),n )` will returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the given range which has a value just greater than `n`. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer  solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Man you are the best brother I really appreciate it. I learned a lot about these methods because of you and will continue to learn because of people like you.